# Convert perl regex to python

Tags: python, regex, perl

The regex expression I'm trying to convert is

```
my $host =~m/([^.])(\.swiss\.ch)/)
```

But I'm not getting the desired result

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Is that the actual Perl regex you have or did you mean to escape the periods in the "swiss ch" part?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to be able to match `*.swiss.ch` domains and addresses:

```
import re
preg = re.compile(r'([^\.]+)\.swiss\.ch')
```

Comment: No need to escape the dot inside the character class. And you also added a `+` quantifier that is missing in the Perl version.

Comment: Please explain in detail. I've just started learning Python and regex expressions. 
I'm really new to both of them

Comment: Somehow the regex looks exactly the same. :)

Comment: @ShvetaRai, take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/qA2aN9/1) for an interactive version of the regex, it is being explained better there than I could do it here. You also might want to take a look at the [regex examples in the module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-examples)